# How to add a fallback font to an existing Unity game?

Tags: unity, windows, modding, fonts, linux

I am trying to make a mod that will fix a game that failed to ship all used fonts with it.

For example, this code point displays in Windows but not under Wine:

> ✔    U+2713

(The reason seems to be a combination of the fact that the game's font is missing this glyph, and Wine does not handle fallback.)

How can I fix this problem?

- Is it possible to add a fallback font with a runtime script?
- Is it possible to modify the resource to add a fallback font?

I feel it is unlikely to be fixed by changing the font. The problem is that I need a [CJK + symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation), and it seems that Wine does not handle fallback. And I don't know of a single font that contains this CJK + symbol.

====Update====
One workaround for Wine is to copy Segoe fonts (Segoe UI symbol for this code point) to Wine.
[Unity Editor manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Font.html) mentions "hard-coded global list of fallback fonts" but does not tells the exact fonts.

Comment: It looks to me like your workaround should be posted as an Answer below.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround for Wine is to copy Segoe fonts (Segoe UI symbol for this code point) to Wine.
Unity Editor manual mentions "hard-coded global list of fallback fonts" but does not tells the exact fonts.

AFAIK Segoe fonts are not free font, so usually modders should not distribute it.
If Wine user is unable to get Segoe fonts, it should be possible to config Wine FontLink as substitution. (I didn't test it)
Full example: https://gist.github.com/swordfeng/c3fd6b6fcf6dc7d7fa8a

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink]
"Arial"="wqy-microhei.ttc"
```